# Actualizar imagen de registro con Jquery y php, mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

tengo mi código para actualizar la foto de cualquier registro en especial, primero esta parte de código se encarga de traer la imagen del registro.

```
<?php
//Incluir archivo de configuración de base de datos
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

//Obtener ID de usuario actual de la sesión
$userId = 1;

//Obtener datos de usuario de la base de datos
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $userId");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

//Foto de perfil de usuario
$userPicture = !empty($row['picture'])?$row['picture']:'no-image.png';
$userPictureURL = 'uploads/images/'.$userPicture;
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="user-box">
        <div class="img-relative">
            <!-- Cargando imagen -->
            <div class="overlay uploadProcess" style="display: none;">
                <div class="overlay-content"><img src="images/loading.gif"/></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Formulario de carga oculto -->
            <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="picUploadForm" target="uploadTarget">
                <input type="file" name="picture" id="fileInput"  style="display:none"/>
            </form>
            <iframe id="uploadTarget" name="uploadTarget" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
            <!-- Enlace de actualización de imagen -->
            <a class="editLink" href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/edit.png"/></a>
            <!-- Imagen de perfil -->
            <img src="<?php echo $userPictureURL; ?>" id="imagePreview">
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            <h4><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es mi código en Jquery para actualizar la imagen sin recargar la ventana.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Si se hace clic en el enlace de edición de imagen
    $(".editLink").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#fileInput:hidden").trigger('click');
    });

    //En el archivo seleccionado para cargar
    $("#fileInput").on('change', function(){
        var image = $('#fileInput').val();
        var img_ex = /(.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif)$/i;

        //validar tipo de archivo
        if(!img_ex.exec(image)){
            alert('Please upload only .jpg/.jpeg/.png/.gif file.');
            $('#fileInput').val('');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('.uploadProcess').show();
            $('#uploadForm').hide();
            $( "#picUploadForm" ).submit();
        }
    });
});

//Después de completar el proceso de carga de imágenes
function completeUpload(success, fileName) {
    if(success == 1){
        $('#imagePreview').attr("src", "");
        $('#imagePreview').attr("src", fileName);
        $('#fileInput').attr("value", fileName);
        $('.uploadProcess').hide();
    }else{
        $('.uploadProcess').hide();
        alert('¡Hubo un error durante la carga del archivo!');
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Y este es el código que procesa todo el formulario y actualiza la imagen del registro upload.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])){
    //Incluir archivo de configuración de base de datos
    include_once 'dbconfig.php';

    //Configuración de carga de archivos
    $result = 0;
    $uploadDir = "uploads/images/";
    $fileName = time().'_'.basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
    $targetPath = $uploadDir. $fileName;

    //Subir archivo al servidor
    if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $targetPath)){
        //Obtener ID de usuario actual de la sesión
        $userId = 1;

        //Actualizar el nombre de la imagen en la base de datos
        $update = $db->query("UPDATE users SET picture = '".$fileName."' WHERE id = $userId");

        //Update status
        if($update){
            $result = 1;
        }
    }

    //Función de carga de JavaScript para mostrar el estado de carga
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.window.completeUpload(' . $result . ','' . $targetPath . '');</script>  ';
}
?>
```

Cabe destacar que lo que se cambia de la base de datos es el nombre de la imagen y la imagen como tal se guarda en una carpeta que después se llama con la ruta.

El problema es que he intentado varias cosas porque mi código no quiere actualizar la imagen se queda cargando y no actualiza, alguien me podria ayudar con el tema? muchisimas gracias.

Comment: ¿Depuraste algo, probaste tus datos y/o variables, detectaste en qué parte falla el código, revisaste el log de errores (de paso evita el uso de `@` en PHP, es una mala práctica porque silencia los errores y dificulta encontrarlos)?

Comment: Hola, asi es ya depure el código acabo de quitar el @ pero igual no me da ningun error solo presiono el boton de editar la imagen luego selecciono la nueva imagen y se queda cargando y no hace más nada. si puedes corre ese mismo código en tu computador para que observes mejor lo que ocurre.

Comment: Es difícil emular este tipo de código, habría que crear tu base de datos, tus tablas, tus archivos, etc. por eso conviene que des la mayor cantidad de detalles posibles. ¿Qué dice el log de errores? Si vas a programar en PHP (o cualquier lenguaje) debes aprender a revisar el log de errores, créeme, te vas a ahorrar muchas horas y muchos dolores de cabeza intentando adivinar dónde falla el código, el log de errores te dice el fallo, te dice la línea donde está etc. Otra cosa que me pregunto es ¿por qué no usas Ajax para esto?